# Swift: Memory pressure event 2 vm 0

Tags: swift, xcode

I saw a message in the Xcode console which is `Received memory pressure event 1 vm pressure 0`. I'm not really sure what causes this and why but I do know this prints when I'm in a camera viewcontroller.  I'm guessing it's nothing to worry about (yet) but is it pointing to something I should fix asap?

```
FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as! UIImage
        let croppedImage = cropToBounds(image: image, width: 10, height: 10)
        self.productImage.image = croppedImage
        print("size: \(croppedImage.size)")
        print("original size: \(image.size)")
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func setupCameraPicker() {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = .camera;
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It means that you are consuming too much memory. Check the Memory consumption. Check if you are not leaking.

Comment: I have this message as well. Xcode's memory gauges tells that I use just 43 MB or 2%

Comment: @maniponken I get the error also. Did you fix this in the end, or find out if it was indeed using too much memory or a memory leak?

Comment: I have not fixed this issue, I am not working on this project anymore either so... but my guess is that it was using too much memory... but don't take my word for it.

Answer (score 2):

**autoreleasepool**

```
autoreleasepool { 
   let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as! UIImage
    let croppedImage = cropToBounds(image: image, width: 10, height: 10)
    self.productImage.image = croppedImage
    print("size: \(croppedImage.size)")
    print("original size: \(image.size)")
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

Try to put your code in autoreleasepool
Foundation’s NSAutoreleasePool type, later abstracted to the @autoreleasepool block, is a very old concept in iOS development. During the Obj-C era of iOS, usage of this type was important to prevent your app's memory from blowing up in specific cases. As ARC and Swift came around and evolved, very few people still have to manually play around with memory, making seeing it become a rare occurrence.